# Nestjs catch 500 error and return the error

Tags: nestjs

When an unhandled error occurs, the front side gets a 500 error without any information about the error. It just receives this:

```
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

But when I check the console, I see what happened and what the error message is. It's ok in the development environment but it's hard to figure out in production. How can I return a complete error message in production instead of just a simple message like `"Internal server error"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you should be doing error handling around things that have a chance to go wrong (database operations, sending emails, validations), but if you're looking for a general error handling mechanism, you can use the [Exception Filters](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) construct that Nest provides to catch errors and manage them as necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I just read this but didn't get my answer.

Comment: I mean, generally all errors in JavaScript have a `message` property, so you could `res.send(exception.message)` (general code, make sure you tailor it to your needs) and it should send back what happened instead of  "Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 3):

NestJS has the `NotFoundException` you can use.

You can implement your own custom Exception filters and add it to your controllers to capture a `NotFoundException` or whatever communication protocol, but this is assuming that you have an **HTTP** communication protocol.

So if http is the only communication protocol you are dealing with then you can just write this into one of your methods inside your service:

```
if (!user) {
  throw new NotFoundException('user not found');
}
```

And you would import that from:

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the answer to this question - you don't need any complicated exception filters, or interceptors, etc. You just need to wrap the code which is causing the 500 in an if statement, and throw a `HttpException` - note, throwing an `Error` will not work.

In other words, you need to resolve this error in your service class, not in your controller.

For example, in your service class:

```
  async getUsers(){
    let response = doSomething();
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      throw new HttpException(
        `Error getting users: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`,
        response.status,
      )
    } else {
      return response.data
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//InternalServerError.filter.ts
import {
    InternalServerErrorException,
    Catch,
    ArgumentsHost,
    ExceptionFilter,
    HttpStatus,
    HttpException
} from "@nestjs/common";
// catch all error
@Catch()
export default class InternalServerErrorExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: Error, host: ArgumentsHost) {
      
        let { message: errMsg, stack: errStack, name: errName } = exception;
        // let errRes = exception.getResponse();
        // let errCode = exception.getStatus();
        let ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        let req = ctx.getRequest();
        let res = ctx.getResponse();
        const statusName = "系统内部错误";
        res.statusCode = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        // HttpException Error
        if (exception instanceof HttpException) {
            // set httpException res to res
            res.status(exception.getStatus()).json(exception.getResponse());
            return;
        }
        // other error to rewirte InternalServerErrorException response
        res.render("Error.ejs", {
            exception,
            errMsg,
            errStack,
            errName,
            statusCode: res.statusCode,
            statusName,
            req
        });
    }
}
```

### then use global filter provider for InternalServerError.filter.ts

```
// app.module.ts
@Module({
providers:[{
        provide: APP_FILTER,
        useClass: InternalServerErrorExceptionFilter
    }])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call Logger.error() at 1 line controller, if still return 500, check request interface, in my case that was a reason

```
@Post('register');
register(@Body() user: UserInterface): any { // UserInterface call 500 exception
  Logger.error('user', user)
```